# How to bind array data in table view in ios?

Tags: uitableview, uiview, ios8, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a custom table view cell that has 4-5 images in custom table view cell . I am trying to bind data in cells but images are getting repeated after 1st cell. All i want ,is to map all url's of array to my uiimageview of all the cells of table view just like images section of google images.

Here is the screenshot of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

And here is what I am getting so far:

[image]

Here is my code :

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


urlArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            @"http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg",
            @"https://farm1.staticflickr.com/2/1418878_1e92283336_m.jpg",
            @"http://i.share.pho.to/68bd6b4c_o.jpeg",
            @"http://i.share.pho.to/a9cf8966_o.jpeg",
            @"http://i.share.pho.to/934e487c_o.jpeg",
            @"http://i.share.pho.to/6343e165_o.jpeg",
            @"http://i.share.pho.to/99a3ffd0_o.jpeg",
            @"http://i.share.pho.to/9968ab24_o.jpeg",
            @"http://i.share.pho.to/9968ab24_o.jpeg",
            @"http://i.share.pho.to/a4cc0bac_o.jpeg",
                            nil];
 }




 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


FzTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSData * imageData1 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [urlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
NSData * imageData2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [urlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + 1]]];
NSData * imageData3 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [urlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+2]]];
NSData * imageData4 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [urlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row +3]]];
NSData * imageData5 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [urlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+4]]];
NSData * imageData6 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [urlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+5]]];



// Configure the cell...

cell.img1.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData1];
cell.img2.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData2];
cell.img3.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData3];
cell.img4.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData4];
cell.img5.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData5];
cell.img6.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData6];

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"cellForRowAtIndexPath" configures a single cell, and is called for each cell in your list. So, for the first cell it will set the 6 images using array indices

> [0,1,2,3,4,5]

The second time it is called (for the second cell) it will use indices

> [2,3,4,5,6]

To get what you asked, you would have to use:

> int mappedIndex = indexPath.Row*6;

Then for each cellImage

> ```
> cell.img1.image =mappedIndex;
> cell.img1.image =mappedIndex+1;
> cell.img1.image =mappedIndex+2;
> ```

etc

This way your indices for cell 1 would be:

```
For cell 1: [0,1,2,3,4,5] 
For cell 2: [6,7,8,9,10,11] 
For cell 3: [12,13,14,15,16]
```

etc
Obviously you need a bigger array for this to work though. I think you should really use a UICollectionView for this thought. A UICollectionView handles a "Grid" of cells. It will then give you events for when each cell is pressed etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can u tell me how to achieve this using collection view ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it by using a UICollectionView, you should replace your tableview with a collection view or use a UICollectionViewController.

It is very similar to the UITableview, except each cell is part of the "grid" of cells instead of row - it has similar delegate callbacks for configuring cells, and getting the count of each section etc.

There is too much for me to explain here, but you can follow a tutorial like: http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

I believe that tutorial also explains how to load images asynchronously (so the network operation of downloading the image doesn't cause your app to freeze while the downloads are in progress).